# Stop Firefox 3.5 from auto-removing downloads after finish?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox 3.5, all items that finish downloading are automatically removed from the Downloads window after they've successfully finished.  Is there an about:config setting that tells Firefox 3.5 to let me manually clear items out instead?  I've been looking for an answer for several days with no success.

Answer (score 1):

The "Remember download history" checkbox in the Privacy preferences pane is unchecked. If you want the download history saved, re-check it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the option `browser.download.manager.retention` to ensure that it exists and is not 0.  See http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Download_Manager_preferences for details.

Answer (score 0):

In tools options privacy there is a tick box for remembering download history that should sort you out.